# What happened to my source code after I turned my game into an executive with cx_freeze?

Tags: python, pygame, cx-freeze

I'm very new to programming. I made a game, or at least something that kinda resembles a game, with python and pygame. I follow this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EY6ZCPxqEtM

to turn my game and its files into an executive. After I made my files into an executive, I moved the old files around, including the source code, to see if the executive could function by itself, and I think I put the source code in the recycling bin. But I restored everything in the recycling bin, so that shouldn't have mattered. My source code was titled "Game1.txt", and I did find the file after searching my computer, but it was much smaller. The old file had over 100 lines of code, and the new one has only like 5.

What happened? can I fix it? I have the game the code made as a .py and a .exe, so at least I still have the game. I could give more information if necessary.

I understand that I am likely being vague, not understanding everything I do, and doing some things I shouldn't, but patience would be appreciated as I am new. Thank you.

Comment: Hey there and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you provide us the source code of your game? It's fine to be new, but we'll need a little more information to help you properly :)

Comment: @PedroMartinsdeSouza that's the problem unfortunately. I can't seem to find the source code. When I said .txt file, I meant the source code. Actually, I'll delete the question and repost it with source code instead of .txt.

Comment: Don’t delete the question, just edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED! There actually wasn't a problem to begin with. I was just a goof and didn't notice that my source code was .py file, while I spent so much time looking for a .txt file, when it never existed to begin with. I just right clicked my .py file, and clicked edit with notepad++. Now I can edit my source code again.